# hyper-v could not initialize memory there is not enough space on the disk (0x80070070)‎

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I have created a virtual machine on a Hyper-V server, Dell PowerEdge with 24 Gb of RAM. I want to have four VMs with 2048 Mb of RAM each. Originally, I created this one (SV-YAMATO) with 512 Mb of RAM, now I want to extend it to 2048 through the Settings, but when I start it I get the following error message (see the screen shot). What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does your c:\ drive have enough space to create the 2GB file needed for the memory?  When you put the VM to sleep it swaps that back out to disk and it precreates the space for that on the drive.

Comment: The C:\ drive has only 227 MB free of 30 GB... However, the E:\ drive which contains all the .vhd files has 1.2 TB free. Isn't there a way to relocate this?

Comment: yeap... export the VM and recreate it on e:...when you create the VM, pay close attention.  It actually asks you about where you want the files created and will default to the c: drive.  In practice I tell the VMs to use e:\ by default which causes it to place all of the VM related files on that disk instead.  (You'll see a few XML files that are related to this)..  For what its worth, 227MB on the host drive on windows is pretty low, but thats a whole other question.

Comment: Ok... I found the option in Hyper-V Settings, there are two folders, Virtual Machines and Virtual Hard Disks (VHD). It works!

Comment: For my own education, did it let you move them?  I was under the impression (possibly wrong impression) that you couldn't move them.  If you can, that is good to know..

Comment: Actually, I had already moved them to my E:\ drive, so the .vhd files on the C:\ were just sitting there using up all my space. I deleted them while the machines were still running without any problems which proves that they were not in use... My guess is that Hyper-V is still using C:\ to swap the memory, but now at least there is space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be out of diskspace on the host. You'll have to reduce the memory used by the VM, since Hyper-V requires a "hibernation file" on the host for when the VM is suspended, as Mike noted.

Comment: There should be a way to set the path for the hibernation file?

Comment: You need to relocate the Hyper-V service to your E:\ drive. Even if the VHDs are on the larger drive, the configuration is on your C:\ drive.

Comment: you can, but you can only set it when the VM is created.  You can hack it by copying over the VHD to a new folder and creating a new VM for it, but i suggest exporting the VM out and recreating it and telling it to use e: instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with Disk Quotas.

In short I did the following:

1. disabled disk quotas
2. started VM
3. enabled quotas
4. Look for user account "NT Virtual MACHINE**GUID**", then select "Do not limit disk usage"

Seems I found a "non standard configuration" to have file shares with disk quotas on the same volume as the VM .vhd's.  Pre-existing VMs and their user account for disk quota's were OK, just a problem for new VM's.